# Google Drive SDK Sample for iOS Not Working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I'm attempting to follow these instructions: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios.

Now the first time I tried this, I got the error mentioned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590773/google-drive-sdk-ios-example), but was able to solve it. The sample app now runs, however it crashes before uploading anything to Google Drive. It stops on the loading screen and gives the following error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)'

What does it mean by "uploading to the wrong URL?" Am I setting something up wrong or is their code not working correctly?

Comment: When i implementated google-maps api for the first time i got the same error in your link. I removed armv7s in build settings -> valid architectures.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix anything. Also for anyone who wants more info, the error seems to be coming from [GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] ... I don't really see what could be wrong with the way I am setting this up that could make this happen. Is anyone else able to duplicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble with this as well today - the error message we're seeing is misleading.

One of the problems I had with my own code was not initializing the authorizer and assigning it to the GTLServiceDrive instance, however if you've followed that sample code exactly then it's done for you (in viewDidLoad).

More likely you haven't enabled "Drive API" in the services tab of the Google APIs console. I had "Drive SDK" switched on instead by mistake (probably just drawn to the only Drive icon...)